# Servlet Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, tomcat, servlets

I am using Tomcat server with Eclipse and I am today running my first servlet.

But I got the following Exception :

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error allocating a servlet instance
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:164)
    org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:206)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:833)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:732)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:619)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:688)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1677)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:900)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1350)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1230)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:164)
    org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:206)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:833)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:732)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:619)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:688)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Tomcat logs.
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**: I am using jdk1.5.0_16 for compiling the class and for Tomcat. I also included the `servlet.jar` file to the project, could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you running?

Comment: I amm using tomcat-5.0.19 , can the version of Tomcat cause such problem ?

Comment: hey Guys , The problem is solved now , the cause was the version of the JDK , I was using jdk1.5.0_16 , but when I replaced it with jdk1.6.0_21 , the problem is solved and the servlet is working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The java version running tomcat is probably older than the code you want to execute. You should update the java version.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is compiled with a different version of Java than the one used to run tomcat. Make sure they are the same.